# Create Composite Primary Key From Association in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models: `Person` and `Team`

Lets just say the models are simple (just assume basic string/int types):

```
team:
  id
  name
  ownerId
```

and

```
person:
  id
  name
```

I want to represent the associations between these two models such that a Person can belong to many Teams and a Team can belong to many Persons (i.e. a many to many relationship).

To do this is straight forward in Sequelize:

```
Team.belongsToMany(Person, {through: 'TeamPerson'})
Person.belongsToMany(Team, {through: 'TeamPerson'})
```

This creates a new table called `TeamPerson` with both `teamId` and `personId`. I assume the primary key of this table is a composite of both IDs.

I also want each team to have a captain:

```
Team.belongsTo(Person {as: 'captain'})
```

This will add `captainId` to the Team model.

Here is my issue, I want a Person to be able to create a Team, but I don't want them to be able to create two teams with the same name. I do, however, want to allow other Persons to create a team with the same name as other Persons. So user ID 1 could not have two teams named "Falcons" but user ID 1 can have one team named "Falcons" and user ID 2 could have a team named "Falcons".

Essentially the name and captainId should be a composite primary key on the Team table. Can anyone give me a tip as to how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query for a previously existing person/project before allowing a new project to be created... roughly:

```
    Person.findAll({
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: Team,
            where : { name : ***TEAM_NAME_PARAM*** }
            attributes: [
                [Sequelize.fn('count', 'id'), 'number_of_teams']
           ]
        }],
        where: { id : ***USER_ID_PARAM***},
        group: ['id']
        })        
        .then(myTeams => {
            if (myTeams.length == 0 || myTeams.Team.number_of_teams == 0) {
               // proceed with creating new team
            } else {
               // give some error message (you already have a team with that name)
            }
            ...
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I'd have to remember to do that though for any query involving creation/updating. Plus is this not more overhead? There must be a way to define it in the model definition

Comment: I was **going** to say that's not possible... but the doc says otherwise.  Checkout the QueryInterface object.   I have no experience with this, as I prefer to create my DB objects in raw SQL.  `create unique index my_new_index on team_table  (team_name, team_captain_id)`  In either case, you'll need some code to inform the user why their new team was rejected.