# Adding an association ( HasManyAddAssociationMixin ) after deleting it with { paranoid: true }

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a user orm associated with a party orm that has something like this

```
  public getParties!: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Party>;
  public addParty!: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Party, number>;
  public hasParty!: HasManyHasAssociationMixin<Party, number>;
  public countParties!: HasManyCountAssociationsMixin;
  public removeParty!: HasManyRemoveAssociationMixin<Party, number>;
```

The association looks like this

```
User.belongsToMany(Party, { through: { model: 'UserParties', paranoid: true }, as: 'Parties' });
```

and it works perfectly when I want to addParty or removeParty, But, If I try adding a party after having removed it, it doesn't work.

This, doesn't work

```
user.addParty(party) // works
user.removeParty(party) // works
user.addParty(party) // Doesn't work
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UserParties_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key ("UserId", "PartyId")=(1, 1) already exists.
```

I know why I got this error, but how I can I make it so it overrides it, in the case it exists but has a deleted_at ?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Any errors or what?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- don't use `paranoid` mode
- include `deletedAt` to an unique constraint/index with all three fields: `UserId`, `PartyId` and `deletedAt`

Sequelize does not support a composite PK in associations. You need to add a separate autogenerated field as a PK

Comment: I knew paranoid only added deleted_at, using your answer I found another post that helped me understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011065/create-composite-primary-key-from-association-in-sequelize, can you turn your answer to bullet points as it seems to be the only two ways to do it